# Why is the function from one file returns 'none' value when calling in another file in Flask Python

Tags: python, function, flask

Good evening, everyone!

I have a problem with returning the value while running my programming code below:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from aldd import *


app = Flask(__name__)

names1=""


@app.route('/hashtags/'+b'<name>'.decode('utf-8'), methods=['GET'])


def hash(name):
    name1 = "#" + name
    d=startet(name1)
    print(d)
    app.config['JSON_AS_ASCII'] = False
    return jsonify({'Segmentation hashtags': d})



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=9876)
```

In my file I call another file named "**aldd**.py" with it's internal function "**def startet(nam)**", which has one argument inside. However, when calling this function in my current file with the argument "**name1**", there's no error and all I get is a "None" value as output.

Basically, I run the program in Chrome browser and it looks like following:

[image: 'NUll value in web-browser']

My **project structur**e looks like this:

[image: My project structure]

I guess the error might be caused by transferring the argument "**name1**" of this function to the same function in "**aldd**.py". But I might be mistaken.

Help me, please!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your `startet` function in `aldd.py` is not returning anything.

Try adding this line at the end of the `startet` function

```
return 'testing testing .. 123'
```

Comment: Okay, so the problem lies in the fact that you were not returning anything from your function. If you don't return anything from a function, it literally returns `None`